# Floating point getting truncated in bison grammar

Tags: parsing, floating-point, bison, lex

I finally got around to learning the basics of lex and bison. The problem I had was that I was calculating how much money I was going to give to my co-worker for picking up a burrito, and didn't like doing it manually.

For example, a $7.75 burrito + 20% tip can be figured out using 7.75*(1 + 20/100.0). However, I'd rather have the computer just take `$7.75 + 20%` and do it for me.

So I made this: https://github.com/tlehman/tipcalc

The lexing rules are

```
%%
\$                 return TOKDOLLAR;
\%                 return TOKPERCENT;
[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*  yylval=atof(yytext); return NUMBER;
[ \t]+             /* eat whitespace */
[\+\-]             return TOKOP;
%%
```

And the parsing rules are

```
%%
start:
    dollars TOKOP percentage
    {
        double dollars = $1;
        double percentage = ($3)/(100.0);
        double total = dollars + dollars*percentage;
        printf("debug: dollars = %f\n", dollars);
        printf("debug: percent = %f\n", percentage);

        printf("%.2f", total);
    }

dollars:
    TOKDOLLAR NUMBER
    {
        $$ = (double)$2;
    }

percentage:
    NUMBER TOKPERCENT
    {
        $$ = (double)$1;
    }

%%
```

The only problem is that dollars is getting handled incorrectly, when I run

```
$ echo '$7.75 + 20%' | ./tipcalc
```

I get this output:

```
debug: dollars = 7.000000 
debug: percent = 0.200000 
8.40
```

The `dollars` value is getting rounded somewhere. I think the rounding is happening after lexing since `percentage` seems to work with all the values I threw at it. I can't figure out where it is happening, have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the values passed around by the Bison-generated parser (yylval and the dollar things) are integers. So unless you explicitly tell Bison they are doubles, they will be integers. This includes yylval, so the truncation happens already here: `yylval=atof(yytext);`

Comment: Okay, If I `#define YYSTYPE double` before including the generated header, then `yylval` is typed as a double.